# How to get current users data from the token stored in the local storage in Next.JS

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, jwt

After being logged in, a token is stored in the local storage and I want to use that token to retrieve the data of the logged in user so I can access it anywhere in the web for example to show it on its profile, any other approach might help.

This is the handleSubmit function for the log in button which gives back a token:

```
 async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/authenticate", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(state),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    if (res.ok) {
      const json = await res.json();
      localStorage.setItem("token", json.token);
      succesfulAlert();
      await router.push("/profile");
    } else {
      wrongCredentialsAlert();
    }
  }
```